# How to use yaml-cpp without exceptions support?

Tags: yaml-cpp

Is it possible to use yaml-cpp without exception support?

Currently, I use yaml-cpp-0.8.0. When I try to compile a program that uses yaml-cpp I get the following error:

```
external/yaml-cpp~override/src/scanscalar.cpp:52:11: error: cannot use 'throw' with exceptions disabled
   52 |           throw ParserException(INPUT.mark(), ErrorMsg::DOC_IN_SCALAR);
      |           ^
```

Since, I have exceptions disabled for performance reasons I wonder if there is a flag/define something that allows me to use yaml-cpp without exception support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, exceptions are hardcoded into the yaml-cpp library so there is no option to turn them off.

The source for the particular function you are asking about looks like this:

```cpp
std::string ScanScalar(Stream& INPUT, ScanScalarParams& params) {
//...
        if (params.onDocIndicator == THROW) {
          throw ParserException(INPUT.mark(), ErrorMsg::DOC_IN_SCALAR);
        }
//...
}
```

... and there are no `#ifdef`s or anything else that could disable the use of exceptions.

---

On a more fundamental level, one of the most central classes in the library, the `Yaml::Node`, doesn't even have `noexcept` move semantics, which I raised an issue about in [Make move constructor and assignment operator noexcept #809](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/issues/809) and tried to fix, but I wasn't able to get that commit in.

The question [Is it possiable to disable exception? #930](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/issues/930) was also raised.